# Python: get list with nearest dates and same size for list with dates and values

Tags: python

I am trying to get list of nearest dates for current list of lists (dates and value)

Have two lists:

```
[["20160901", 0.244], ["20160902", 0.232], ["20160906", 0.214],
["20160909", 0.235], ["20160910", 0.244], ["20160911", 0.271],     
["20160912", 0.239], ["20160914", 0.25], ...]
```

length is X

and:

```
[["20160907", -9.39979076385498, -6.318868160247803], 
["20160913", -10.568793296813965, -6.815752029418945], ... ]
```

length is Y

Need to get first list with length is Y and nearest dates for second list.

e.g.

```
[["20160906", 0.214], ["20160912", 0.239], ...]
```

Here is my code:

```
def nearest_date(dates, pivot):
    return min(dates, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

But I get lists different sizes.

Comment: Try something on your own first!! Show us the code. If there is some issue then we can help

Comment: You chose `["20160912", 0.239]` over `["20160914", 0.25]` because 0.239 is less than 0.25 ??

Comment: Don't care about values. Need to get lists only with nearest dates and output lists must be same size like second list.

Comment: So the output list can contain either `["20160912", 0.239]` or `["20160914", 0.25]` as both are equally close to `"20160913"`??

Comment: @User_Targaryen yeah, either

Comment: Can `abs()` take strings?? You are comparing 2 strings via abs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list_dates = [["20160901", 0.244], ["20160902", 0.232], ["20160906", 0.214],
["20160909", 0.235], ["20160910", 0.244], ["20160911", 0.271],     
["20160912", 0.239], ["20160914", 0.25]]

list_comp = [["20160907", -9.39979076385498, -6.318868160247803], 
["20160913", -10.568793296813965, -6.815752029418945]]

[ min(list_dates, key = lambda x: abs(int(x[0])-int(p[0]))) for p in list_comp ]
```

result :

```
[['20160906', 0.214], ['20160912', 0.239]]
```

Comment: `list_z = [ min(list_dates, key = lambda x: abs(int(x[0])-int(p[0]))) for p in list_comp ]` Then `print list_z`